# How to change dropdownlist width to 100% using CSS

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a dropdownlist like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaxPayerType"  runat="server"
        CssClass="SearchSectionInputs SearchSectionSelect">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Hüquqi şəxs</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Fiziki şəxs</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and my classes are as follows:

```
.SearchSectionInputs
{
    font-family: Segoe UI Semibold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    /*width: 215px;*/
    width: 90%;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
    outline: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}            
.SearchSectionSelect
{    
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

But 100% doesn't work for dropdownlist. Why?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Also, what does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: I think you should only put only one class on your dropdown list

Comment: @J.P. ten Berge, rendered HTML look like this:
<select name="ctl00$cph_Body$ddlTaxPayerType" id="ddlTaxPayerType" class="SearchSectionInputs">
 <option selected="selected" value="0">Hüquqi şəxs</option>
 <option value="1">Fiziki şəxs</option>

</select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following code:

```
<style>
.SearchSectionInputs
{
    font-family: Segoe UI Semibold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    /*width: 215px;*/
    width: 90%;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
    outline: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}            
.SearchSectionSelect
{    
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
</style>


<select class="SearchSectionInputs SearchSectionSelect">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

It renders 100% the width of the page for me. Your problem is more likely to be other CSS issues on your page. Hope this helps.

Comment: I found own error. I was not set width of my the parent control. thanks

Comment: Cool, like I said the problem is not with what you posted but likely to be another CSS issue on the page. Glad I could help.